# Removing Layer on ArcGIS API For JavaScript>

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers

I am adding a markers layer called `layer1` like this to map

```
function drawPoints(mapInfo) {
  layer1 = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
    for (var i = 0; i < mapInfo.length; i++) {
           var projects = mapInfo[i];
           var project = new esri.geometry.Point(projects.Longitude, projects.Latitude);
           project = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(project);
           var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("img/map/marker.png", 18, 18);
           projectInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
           projectInfoTemplate.setTitle("Project Details");
           projectInfoTemplate.setContent('<div class="row"></div> ');
           var projectsG = new esri.Graphic(project, symbol).setInfoTemplate(projectInfoTemplate);
           layer1.add(projectsG);
           }
          map.addLayer(layer1);
 }
```

now in next request I need to clear map so I used the

```
map.removeLayer(layer1);
```

but this is causing error because the `layer1` still not created at first request. Now I need to check `IF` the map has a layer called `layer1` then removeit. Here is a pseudo code of what I need to do:

```
if(map.has/contains/include(layer1){
  map.removeLayer(layer1);
}
```

can you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: A little confused about your request, sounds like you are adding a layer and then immediately removing it automatically. Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure it is loaded. I couldn't get layer1 to get recognized when I used 'load', but this works fine. Just click on map and the points will go away.

```
    map.on("click", function unloadPoints() {
        map.removeLayer(layer1);
    });
```

I thought this would work, but like I said it didn't see layer1. So explore along these lines.

```
    layer1.on("load", function unloadPoints() {
        map.removeLayer(layer1);
    });
```

Read more about events here
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_events.html